# Memory usage of neural network, Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to develop a model for denoising images. I've been reading up on how to calculate memory usage of a neural network and the standard approach seems to be:

```
    params = depth_n x (kernel_width x kernel_height) x depth_n-1 + depth
```

By summing all parameters together in my network, I end up getting **1,038,097** which approximates to **4.2MB**. It seems I have done a slight miscalculation in the last layer since Keras ends up getting **1,038,497** params. Nevertheless, this is a small difference. 4.2MB is just the parameters, and I've seen somewhere that one should **multiply by 3** to include backprop and other needed calculations. This would then approximate to 13MB.

I have approximately 11 GB of GPU memory to work with, yet this model gets exhausted. Where does all the extra needed memory come from? What am I missing? I know this post might be labeled as duplicate, but none of the others seems to catch the topic which I am asking about.

My model:

```
    def network(self):
        weights = RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05, seed=None)
        input_img = Input(shape=(self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channels))
        conv1 = Conv2D(1024, (3,3), activation='tanh', kernel_initializer=weights,
                padding='same', use_bias=True)(input_img)
        conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='tanh', kernel_initializer=weights,
                padding='same', use_bias=True)(conv1)
        conv3 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='tanh', kernel_initializer=weights,
                padding='same', use_bias=True)(conv2)
        conv4 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=weights,
                padding='same', use_bias=True)(conv3)
        conv5 = Conv2D(64, (7,7), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=weights,
                padding='same', use_bias=True)(conv4)
        conv6 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=weights,
                padding='same', use_bias=True)(conv5)
        conv7 = Conv2D(32, (5,5), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=weights,
                padding='same', use_bias=True)(conv6)
        conv8 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=weights,
                padding='same', use_bias=True)(conv7)
        conv9 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=weights,
                padding='same', use_bias=True)(conv8)
        decoded = Conv2D(1, (5,5), kernel_initializer=weights,
                padding='same', activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True)(conv8)
        return input_img, decoded


    def compiler(self):
        self.model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop', loss='mse')
        self.model.summary()
```

I assume my model is silly in a lot of ways and that there are multiple things to improve (dropout, other filter sizes and numbers, optimizers etc.) and all suggestions are received gladly, but the actual question still remain. Why does this model consume so much memory? Is it due to the extremely high depth of `conv1`?

Model summary:

```
    Using TensorFlow backend.
    _________________________________________________________________
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
    =================================================================
    input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 1751, 480, 1)      0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 1751, 480, 1024)   10240     
    _________________________________________________________________
    conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 1751, 480, 64)     589888    
    _________________________________________________________________
    conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 1751, 480, 64)     36928     
    _________________________________________________________________
    conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 1751, 480, 64)     36928     
    _________________________________________________________________
    conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 1751, 480, 64)     200768    
    _________________________________________________________________
    conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 1751, 480, 64)     102464    
    _________________________________________________________________
    conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 1751, 480, 32)     51232     
    _________________________________________________________________
    conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 1751, 480, 32)     9248      
    _________________________________________________________________
    conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 1751, 480, 1)      801       
    =================================================================
    Total params: 1,038,497
    Trainable params: 1,038,497
    Non-trainable params: 0
    _________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: what's the output of the `model.summary()` function? Can you provide it, please?

Comment: There, appended in the post.

Comment: It is not just the parameters of the model that take up memory. You must consider the memory reserved for activations and other miscellaneous data.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. I've tried to read up on how to try and estimate it, but there seems to be little information about it. The only one I've seen is as mentioned, that one has to multiply number of parameters by three to get an estimate of backprop and activations etc. Aparantly it does not fit at all, but how do I calculate it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are correct, this is due to the number of filters in `conv1`. What you must compute is the memory required to store the activations:

As shown by your `model.summary()`, the output size of this layer is `(None, 1751, 480, 1024)`. For a single image, this is a total of `1751*480*1024` pixels. As your image is likely in `float32`, each pixel takes 4 bytes to store. So the output of this layer requires `1751*480*1024*4` bytes, which is around 3.2 GB per image just for this layer.

If you were to change the number of filters to, say, 64, you would only need around 200 MB per image.

Either change the number of filters or change the batch size to 1.

Comment: Finally an explanation of what I was wondering! Thanks, perfectly explained.